# PHP Max execution time is 0 but still times out

Tags: php

I have a php script that continues to timeout at 45 seconds. I have done everything I can find with execution time and currently have the following.

In my php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 0
```

In my .htaccess:

```
# set timeout to 10 minutes
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value max_execution_time 600
</IfModule>
```

And in the script that timesout:

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
set_time_limit(0);
```

In the script, when I echo ini_get('max_execution_time') I get 0 so it looks like everything is right. Is are there other resource limits at play that are keeping the script from running? I've researched memory_limit, input time, etc but am thinking there's something here I don't know about.

The script does a while loop against a table and then crawls different sites according to the record. When I limit the return to 1 or 2 records it works fine but any more than that it goes to a 404 page not found. To me this means it times out but does the 404 error indicate something else is going on? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it is the time limit on the PHP execution? Are you getting an error? Are you trying to keep a database connection open? Need to see the code you are running to determine better. Could be that your connection to your table is dropping too.

Comment: 404 usually indicates 'not found' ... as if for one of the records, your processing requires fetching a non-existant resource. Show some code.

Comment: How do you crawl the websites? cURL? Streams? Something else?

Comment: With everyone's help I've narrowed it down to something with phantomjs. Knowing it's not actually timing out is a great help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 404 error does not mean your script times out, it just means that those URLs you hit are `Not Found`.

You need to evaluate your script and maybe send a `HEAD` request to check the status code.

See [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) a list of HTTP status code and their meaning.